# Why am I getting arithmetic discrepancies between Debug and Release mode, and how can I remedy them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

In my program this fragment:

```
  trace.log(
   String.Format("a= {0:R} b= {1:R} a<b= {2}", 
    b.GetPixel(447, 517).GetBrightness(), (100F / 255F),
    b.GetPixel(447, 517).GetBrightness() < (100F / 255F))
  );
```

outputs this in Debug\prog.exe:

```
 a= 0.392156869 b= 0.392156869 a<b= False
```

but this different result in Release\prog.exe:

```
 a= 0.392156869 b= 0.392156869 a<b= True
```

Can anyone explain why the same operands give a different comparision result? And recommend a remedy, ideally program-wide such as a compiler switch? Thanks.

EDIT: **Clarification:** the above results are from launching Debug\prog.exe and Release\prog.exe in Windows Explorer.

EDIT: **Further info:** executing from VS, "Start Debugging" gives False (i.e. the accurate result, same as WE-launched Debug\prog.exe), and "Start without debugging" gives True (i.e. the inaccurate result, same as WE-launched Release\prog.exe.

EDIT: **Alternative test cases** having literals substituted

These two cases

```
  trace.log(
   String.Format("a= {0:R} b= {1:R} a<b= {2}",
    0.392156869F, 0.392156869F, 
    0.392156869F < 0.392156869F)
  );
  trace.log(
   String.Format("a= {0:R} b= {1:R} a<b= {2}",
    0.392156869F, (100F / 255F),
    0.392156869F < (100F / 255F))
  );
```

show no discrepancy in Debug and Release output. This case:

```
  trace.log(
   String.Format("a= {0:R} b= {1:R} a<b= {2}",
    b.GetPixel(447, 517).GetBrightness(), 0.392156869F,
    b.GetPixel(447, 517).GetBrightness() < 0.392156869F)
  );
```

shows the same discrepancy (and inaccuracy in Release) as the original test case.

EDIT: Belated **minimal test case demoing the problem**

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb( 255, 100, 100, 100 );
trace.log(
 String.Format("a= {0} b= {1} a<b= {2}",
 c.GetBrightness(), 0.392156869F,
 c.GetBrightness() < 0.392156869F)
);
```

outputs this correct result in Debug\prog.exe:

```
 a= 0.392156869 b= 0.392156869 a<b= False
```

but this incorrect result in Release\prog.exe:

```
 a= 0.392156869 b= 0.392156869 a<b= True
```

EDIT: **Remedies**

1) From Peter's answer below:

```
trace.log(
 String.Format("a= {0:R} b= {1:R} a<b= {2}",
  c.GetBrightness(), 0.392156869F, 
  c.GetBrightness().CompareTo(0.392156869F)<0)
);
```

2) From ChrisJJ, the questioner (**UPDATED**):

```
float comp = c.GetBrightness();
trace.log(
 String.Format("a= {0:R} b= {1:R} a<b= {2}", 
 comp, 0.392156869F,
 comp < 0.392156869F)
);
```

I think this adds to the evidence for a Release-mode compiler bug.

Comment: What does the value of GetPixel return exactly? I would like to test this myself and I suspect that this is the result of rounding between Debug and Release when calculating the brightness in GetBrightness.

Comment: It returns Color.FromArgb( 255, 100, 100, 100 ) and though I though I'd found this substitution failed to show the problem, I now find in fact it does, so I have added this case to the question. Thanks P.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most likely the result of different floating point rules between debug mode and release mode (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/03/25/is-floating-point-math-deterministic.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683059/are-floating-point-numbers-consistent-in-c-can-they-be)).

Update:

Thanks to your new update to the question, I was able to reproduce the problem on my machine (64-bit Windows).  This appears to happen only when setting the platform to X86; the X64 and AnyCPU platforms show the correct result in release mode.  Probably, when the platform is X86, the common language runtime applies X86 emulation in 64-bit machines and apparently messed up in the comparison operator.

However, I found a possible workaround:  Use CompareTo instead of the "<" and ">" operators, like this:

```
c.GetBrightness().CompareTo(0.392156869F)<0
```

On my machine, this will provide the same correct results in X86 as in X64 and AnyCPU.

Comment: Thanks for those articles Peter, but I don't actually see there any floating point rule that invalidates the Language Specifications' definition of the < operator and hence supports the Release case's non-compliance with that definition.

Comment: Responmding to your edit. "Any of these operations, especially the divisions, might be the cause of different rounding results between Debug and Release Modes." Is this not disproved by the fact that Format R shows the expression's numeric value is identical Debug v. Release?

Comment: Responding to your update. .CompareTo does solve it here. Another solution is to wrap the "<" in a function. ISTM this indicates a ratehr poor optimiser! Thanks again Peter.