# Assert.AreEqual() with System.Double getting really confusing

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, floating-point, clr

#### Description

This is not a real world example! Please don't suggest using `decimal` or something else.

I am only asking this because I really want to know why this happens.

I recently saw the awesome Tekpub Webcast **Mastering C# 4.0 with Jon Skeet** again.

On episode **7 - Decimals and Floating Points** it is going really weird and even our 
**Chuck Norris of Programming (aka Jon Skeet)** does not have a real answer to my question.
Only a *might be*.

#### Question: Why did `MyTestMethod()` fail and `MyTestMethod2()` pass?

#### Example 1

```
[Test]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    double d = 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;

    Console.WriteLine("d = " + d);
    Assert.AreEqual(d, 1.0d);
}
```

This results in

> d = 1
>
> Expected: 0.99999999999999989d
>     But was:  1.0d

#### Example 2

```
[Test]
public void MyTestMethod2()
{
    double d = 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;
    d += 0.1d;

    Console.WriteLine("d = " + d);
    Assert.AreEqual(d, 0.5d);
}
```

This results in success

> d = 0,5

But why ?

#### Update

Why doesn't `Assert.AreEqual()` cover that?

Comment: You should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Simply luck. It looks like the second one rounded in your favor, the first didn't. You have undefined behavior, so don't expect any logical explanation.

Comment: @Oded i know that, but why `Assert.AreEqual()` does not cover that ?

Comment: @dknaack - How could it? The overloads that take 2 parameters are the generic one and the one taking 2 objects. You can use one of the overloads that _specifically_ takes `doubles` and that also takes the error delta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I haven't checked what `Assert.AreEqual` does... but I suspect that by default it's *not* applying any tolerance. I wouldn't *expect* it to behind my back. So let's look for another explanation...

You're basically seeing a coincidence - the answer after four additions *happens* to be the exact value, probably because the lowest bit gets lost somewhere when the magnitude changes - I haven't looked at the bit patterns involved, but if you use `DoubleConverter.ToExactString` (my own code) you can see *exactly* what the value is at any point:

```
using System;

public class Test
{    
    public static void Main()
    {
        double d = 0.1d;
        Console.WriteLine("d = " + DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d));
        d += 0.1d;
        Console.WriteLine("d = " + DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d));
        d += 0.1d;
        Console.WriteLine("d = " + DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d));
        d += 0.1d;
        Console.WriteLine("d = " + DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d));
        d += 0.1d;        
        Console.WriteLine("d = " + DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d));
    }
}
```

Results (on my box):

```
d = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
d = 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
d = 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
d = 0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
d = 0.5
```

Now if you start with a different number, it doesn't work itself out in the same way:

(Starting with d=10.1)

```
d = 10.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375
d = 10.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875
d = 10.2999999999999989341858963598497211933135986328125
d = 10.39999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375
d = 10.4999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

So basically you happened to get lucky or unlucky with your test - the errors cancelled themselves out.

Comment: I know about your `DoubleConverter` class. You show them in the Webcast. But it was hard to understand, because the AssertAreEqual() mistake.Now its clear... Damn so many right answers...

Comment: Rather than converting to a string, you really ought to be using the Assert.AreEqual(double, double, double) overload, where the last double is a delta value indicating the accuracy of the comparison, as mentioned below, as well as here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243458.aspx

Comment: @JoelB: The string conversion here is only to show what the exact value was.

Comment: Is '(Starting with d=0.1)' suppose to be '(Starting with d=10)' ?

Comment: @RGudkov: yup, fixed. (Well, 10.1)

Answer (score 84):

`Assert.AreEqual()` **does** cover that; you have to use the overload with a third `delta` argument:

```
Assert.AreEqual(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1, 0.3, 0.00000001);
```

Comment: what about collectionsAssert.AreEqual()?

Comment: @cikatomo what about it?  There are no collections in the question.

Comment: I am only asking if you know, because I need the same but for collection

Comment: @cikatomo I see.  In that case, you can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I got a NUnit 2005 when I used the above, and the recommended change by VS was to use the constraint model. Adding it on here so that anyone else can also refer to it: `Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected).Within(0.00000001));`

Answer (score 16):

Because Doubles, like all floating point numbers, are <strike>**approximations**, not absolute values</strike> binary (base-2) representations, which may not be able to perfectly represent base-10 fractions (the same way that base-10 cannot represent 1/3 perfectly).  So the fact that the second one happens to round to the correct value when you perform equality comparison (and the fact that the first one doesn't) is just luck, and not a bug in the framework or anything else.

Also, read this: [Casting a result to float in method returning float changes result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795550/casting-result-to-float-in-method-returning-float-changes-result)

Assert.Equals does not cover this case because [the principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) states that since every other built-in numeric value type in .NET defines .Equals() to perform an equivalent operation of ==, so Double does so as well.  Since in fact the two numbers that you are generating in your test (the literal 0.5d and the 5x sum of .1d) are not `==` equal (the actual values in the processors' registers are different) Equals() returns false.

It is not the framework's intent to break the generally accepted rules of computing in order to make your life convenient.

Finally, I'd offer that NUnit has indeed realized this problem and according to http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.5 offers the following method to test floating point equality within a tolerance:

```
Assert.That( 5.0, Is.EqualTo( 5 );
Assert.That( 5.5, Is.EqualTo( 5 ).Within(0.075);
Assert.That( 5.5, Is.EqualTo( 5 ).Within(1.5).Percent;
```

Comment: Yes, i know that, but why Assert.AreEqual() does not cover that ?

Comment: Because the IEEE standard definition for floating point arithmetic (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4610935) does not say that it should.

Comment: So you agree?, really confusing. But of course there must be an answer.

Comment: @ChrisShain MSTest also realizes this; the `double` overload of the `AreEqual` method has a third "delta" argument.  The "Assert.Equals" method in MSTest is not the method in question; that's just the overload inherited from `object`.  Its documentation says "To compare two instances of an object, use the AreEqual method."

Answer (score 9):

[`Assert.AreEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal.aspx) does take that into account.

But in order to do so, you need to supply your margin of error - the delta within the difference between the two float values are deemed equal *for your application*.

There are two overloads to `Assert.AreEqual` that take only two parameters - a generic one `(T, T)` and a non generic one - `(object, object)`. These can only do the default comparisons.

Use one of the overloads that take `double` and that also has a parameter for the delta.

Answer (score 4):

This is the feature of computer floating point arithmetics
(http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/progintro/sx5.html)

> It's important to remember that the precision of floating-point
>   numbers is usually limited, and this can lead to surprising results.
>   The result of a division like 1/3 cannot be represented exactly (it's
>   an infinitely repeating fraction, 0.333333...), so the computation (1
>   / 3) x 3 tends to yield a result like 0.999999... instead of 1.0.
>   Furthermore, in base 2, the fraction 1/10, or 0.1 in decimal, is also
>   an infinitely repeating fraction, and cannot be represented exactly,
>   either, so (1 / 10) x 10 may also yield 0.999999.... For these reasons
>   and others, floating-point calculations are rarely exact. When working
>   with computer floating point, you have to be careful not to compare
>   two numbers for exact equality, and you have to ensure that ``round
>   off error'' doesn't accumulate until it seriously degrades the results
>   of your calculations.

You should explicit set the precision for Assert

For example:

```
double precision = 1e-6;
Assert.AreEqual(d, 1.0, precision);
```

It's work for you sample. I often use this way in my code, but precision depending on the situation

Answer (score 1):

This is because floating point numbers lose precision. The best way to compare equals is to subtract the numbers and verify the different is less then a certain number such as .001 (or to whatever precision you need). Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=VS.95%29.aspx specifically the Floating-Point Values and Loss of Precision section.

Comment: i know that, but why Assert.AreEqual() does not cover that ?

Comment: @dknaack - You may want to clarify your question then... since that's not what you asked...

Comment: Precision varies based on each application. I guessing it just calls equals and tries to compare. So you application might require 3 digits but mine requires 6. Equal could not handle that. (Not 100% sure either but guessing)

Answer (score 0):

`0.1` can't be represented exactly in a double because of it's internal format.

Use decimal if you want to represent base 10 numbers.

If you want to compare doubles check whether they are within a very small amount of each other.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only difference between `decimal` and `double` is the precision (96 vs 64 bits).  `decimal` would likely have the same problem since it still is a floating-point type data structure. If you need to compare decimal values of a known number of digits exactly, then multiply everything by a multiple of 10 until they're all integers first.

Comment: That's not correct, decimal is built to store base 10 numbers exactly (up to a point obviously).

Comment: @jamietre `decimal` is a base-10 floating point data structure, so values like 0.1 and 0.2 have an exact representation as `decimal` values.  `double` is a base-2 floating point system, and 0.1 and 0.2 repeat infinitely in that system, so they cannot be represented exactly as `double` values.