# In C and Objective C, should we almost never cast a float or double value to integer just using (int)?

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-accuracy

I just ran into a situation in Objective-C where:

```
NSLog(@"%i", (int) (0.2 * 10));         // prints 2
NSLog(@"%i", (int) ((1.2 - 1) * 10));   // prints 1
```

so I wonder, if the value is a float or double, and we want an integer, should we never just use `(int)` to do the casting, but use `(int) round(someValue)`?  Or, to flip the question around, when should we just use `(int)`, but in those situations, can't `(int) round(someValue)` can also do the job, so we should almost always use `(int) round(someValue)`?

Comment: It obviously depends on what you want. Sometimes you need to round first, sometimes not.

Comment: the question is, WHEN do we not need round first?  I can never afford to have a 2.0 to cast to a 1, if the 2.0 comes from (1.2 - 1) * 10

Comment: @動靜能量 If you can *never* afford to have 2.0 cast to a 1, then *never* cast. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: But what if it's actually `(1.199999999 - 1)*10`? There's no rule for all cases. You have to decide case-by-case.

Comment: Casting to int (by theory), merely truncates the decimal point and anything behind it.  So what in the world is going on in this case?

Comment: @benzado never cast?  But I want an integer... or display it as an integer... is it true that `printf` or `stringWithFormat`'s `%.0f` always uses `round` to do it?

Comment: @動靜能量 Cast the output of `round` or `roundf`.

Comment: @benzado But it's assumed that casting as an int already rounds down (via truncating).  Is this not the case in objective-c?

Comment: @Daniel do you mean what if it is `(1.199999999 - 1)*10` and we want the floor (that is, we want 1)?  Then in this case, isn't it better to clearly state that using the `floor` function?  I really don't like 2.0 casted to 2 and (1.2 - 1) * 10 casted to 1

Comment: @Highrule it is with floating point precision where (1.2 - 1) * 10 comes out as 1.9999999999999999999

Comment: I meant what if your `1.2` isn't really `1.2` but something slightly smaller? Should that come out as 2 or as 1? Note that with standard `double`s, `1.2 - 1` is actually `0.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875` while with `float`s, it's `0.2000000476837158203125`.

Comment: Floating Point Rounding seems to be the culprit as everyone is mentioning:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911440/strange-behavior-when-casting-a-float-to-int-in-c-sharp

Comment: In general, casting a float/double to an int (with or without rounding) should be very rare, so you can easily take the time to carefully consider the implications of each case.  (You do, of course, need to first understand the approximate nature of IEEE floating-point numbers.)

Comment: @Daniel so I think it is a tough one when we want the floor and double or float will give 1 and 2 respectively (then what is a solution in this situation?).  If we want it rounded, then `(int)round(someValue)` should do it no matter it is float or double?

Comment: Floating point numbers prove the existence of <preferred-deity/deities> by negation, as they are clearly the work of <preferred-personification-of-evil>.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is not converting floating-point values to integer but the rounding errors that occur with floating-point numbers. When you use floating-point, you should understand it well.

The common implementation of float and double use IEEE 754 binary floating-point values. These values are represented as a significand multiplied by a power of two multiplied by a sign (+1 or -1). For floats, the significand is a 24-bit binary numeral, with one bit before the “decimal point” (or “binary point” if you prefer). E.g., the number 1.25 has a significand of 1.01000000000000000000000. For doubles, the significand is a 53-bit binary numeral, with one bit before the point.

Because of this, the values of the decimal numerals .1 and 1.1 cannot be exactly represented. They must be approximated. When you write “.1” or “1.1” in source code, the compiler will convert it to a double that is very near the actual value. Sometimes that result will be slightly greater than the actual value. Sometimes it will be slightly lower than the actual value.

When you convert float to int, the result is (by definition) only the integer portion of the value (the value is truncated toward zero). So, if your value was slightly greater than a positive integer, you get the integer. If your value was slightly less than a positive integer, you get the next lower integer.

If you expect that exact mathematics would give you an integer results, and the floating-point operations you are performing are so few and so simple that the errors have not accumulated to much, then you can round the floating-point value to an integer, using the round function. In simple situations, you can also round by adding .5 before truncation, as by writing “(int) (f + .5)”.

Comment: if we want the floor of a float or double, I wonder if there is a practice that does `(int) (f + 0.000000001)` or some other small number, so that a 2.0 won't be truncated to a 2 sometimes and a 1 sometimes.

Comment: 2.0 is never truncated to 1. The only time “(int) f” evaluates to 1 is when 1 <= f < 2. The situation you are thinking of is when f appears to be 2.0 because you have displayed it with limited precision, so the display process rounded it. If, in fact, you have calculated an f that is very near 2 but is less than 2, and you want to get 2 as a result, then one solution is to add a small value before casting. Since rounding errors differ in each algorithm that uses floating-point, the value to add, or other process to get a correct result, may differ, and there is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: Aha, it was for     `NSLog(@"%i", (int) ((1.2 - 1) * 10));` and 
    `NSLog(@"%i", (int) ((1.2f - 1) * 10));` where the first line shows a 1 and the second line shows a 2

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want. Obviously, a straight cast to `int` will be faster than a call to `round`, whereas round will give out more accurate values.

Unless you are doing code that relies upon speed to be effective (in which case, floating point values might not be the best to use, either), I would say that it's worth it to call `round`. Even if it only changes something you display on-screen by one pixel, when dealing with certain things (angle measure, colors, etc.) The more accuracy you can have the better.

EDIT: Simple test to back up my claim of casting being faster than rounding:

Tested on Macbook Pro:

- 2.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- Mac OS 10.7.4
- Apple LLVM 3.1 Compiler
- -O0 (no optimization)

Code:

```
int value;
void test_cast()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
    {
        value += (int) (((i / 1000.0) - 1.0) * 10.0);
    }

    printf("test_cast: %lu\n", clock() - start);
}

void test_round()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
    {
        value += round(((i / 1000.0) - 1.0) * 10.0);
    }

    printf("test_round: %lu\n", clock() - start);
}

int main()
{
    test_cast();
    test_round();
}
```

Results:

```
test_cast: 11895
test_round: 14353
```

Note: I know that `clock()` isn't the best profiling function, but it does show that `round()` at least uses more CPU cycles.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but you don't want to track money amounts with float/doubles, even using round().

Comment: @PiotrKalinowski true, that was just an example.

Comment: Is it even obvious that casting is faster? It *seems* like it should be, but doing a quick web search led me to an article (from 10 years ago) describing how an (int) cast would flush the FPU pipeline. My point is: premature optimization, root of all evil, etc. etc.

Comment: @benzado I'm doing a simple test right now, but I'll get back to you.

Comment: @benzado updated my answer, with 'proof' of casting being faster.

Comment: @Richard if the situation is some simple calculations done every 1/60 of a second (invoked by `CADisplayLink`) then the time issue isn't so important

Comment: @動靜能量 If that is the case, then I say go ahead and use `round`. If you run into performance problems, they probably aren't there.

Comment: You might want to change `(((i / 1000) - 1) * 10)` to `(((i / 1000.) - 1.) * 10.)` so the expression actually contains floating point operations.

Comment: @Blastfurnace ah, good point fixed. The results remain the same, however. Casting is still faster than rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to int rounds a float or double value towards zero.

1.1 -> 1,   1.99999999999 -> 1,   2.0 -> 2

-1.1 -> -1,   -1.999999999 -> -1,   -2 -> -2

Is that what you want? If yes, that's what you should do. If not, what do you want?

Floating-point arithmetic always gives rounding errors. So for example 0.2 * 10 will give a number that is close to 2. Might be a little bit less, or a little bit more, or by pure chance it might be exactly 2. Therefore (int) (0.2 * 10) might be 1 or 2, because "a little bit less than 2" will be converted to 1.

round (x) will round to the nearest integer. Again, if you calculate round (1.4 + 0.1), the sum of 1.4 and 0.1 is some number very close to 1.5, maybe a bit less, maybe a bit more, so you don't know if it gets rounded to 1.0 or 2.0.

Would you want all numbers from 1.5 to 2.5 to be rounded to 2? Use (int) round (x). You might get a slightly different result if x is 1.5 or 2.5. Maybe you want numbers up to 1.9999 to be rounded down, but 1.99999999 rounded to 2. Use double, not float, and calculate (int) (x + 0.000001).