# Float Value Is Lost in Int

Tags: c#, .net, casting, floating-point, int

Trying to cast float to int but there's something missing

```
float submittedAmount = 0.51f;

int amount = (int)(submittedAmount * 100);
```

[image: here is watch. look at the variable values]

Why is the answer 50?

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911440/strange-behavior-when-casting-a-float-to-int-in-c-sharp

Comment: You may need to apply rounding to the float before casting to an int.

Answer (score 5):

Because of floating point aritmethics, the multiplied value isn't exactly *51*. When I tried now, *0.51f * 100* gave the result *50.9999990463257*.

And when you parse *50.9999990463257* to and int, you surely get *50*.

If you want calculations like this to be exact, you will have to use a type like `decimal` instead of `float`.

If you want to understand why, read the article I have linked below.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
int amount = (int)(submittedAmount * 100.0);
```

When you write `0.51f` is not exactly `0.51`

Read this great article called [`What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: How will changing 100 to 100.0 help? Did you read the article? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert class. Otherwise the answer still will be 50.

```
 var amount  = Convert.ToInt32(submittedAmount * 100.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

`0.51f` is actually `0.509999999999`. because floating points are imprecise.

I would like to add that, do not use `float` for monetary calculations. Use `decimal` instead.