# Error in float to long conversion

Tags: c#

I'm guessing this is due to floating point and accuracy but I just wanted to check to ensure that there's nothing else that I'm missing.

I've got a float (stored in info.Amount) of 1007.62 this gets multiplied by 100 and cast to a long. At this point I get a value of 100761.

[image]

Is this just the good old rounding error that we encounter with Doubles being applied? The only way I can think this could happen is if underneath it's actually stored as 1007.6199999999999 (but rounded for display purposes). Then after the multiplication the conversion to a long ignores everything after the decimal point?

Comment: seems this was discussed/answered before, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911440/strange-behavior-when-casting-a-float-to-int-in-c-sharp

Comment: @03Usr: Thanks - Didn't come up with anything when I searched/similar questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Convert.ToInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.convert.toint64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. This produces the correct value.

LinqPad-Testcode:

```
float z = 1007.62f;
z.Dump();

float x = z *100;
x.Dump();

long l = (long) (z*100);
l.Dump();

l = Convert.ToInt64(z*100);
l.Dump();

l = Convert.ToInt64(x);
l.Dump();
```

Result is:

```
1007,62
100762
100761
100762
100762
```

The cast `(long) (z*100)` uses the CIL-instruction `conv.i8` that converts to Int64, pushes Int64 on stack, while `Convert.ToInt64` uses `Math.Round(double)` to convert/cast to Int64.

A special note on `conv.i8` is

> Conversion from floating-point numbers to integer values truncates the
>   number toward zero.

Comment: Indeed - that's actually the fix that I opted for as you can see in my screenshot I checked a couple of different approaches.

Comment: @Ian, ah ok i didn´t noticed that in your image.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think this is due to the variable you might declared.

Take the following sample:

```
       double amount = 1007.62;
       long result = (long) (amount*100);
```

result absolutely will be 100762 without any fraction or roundness. As a matter of fact, 1007.62 is a double number which should not be stored as float that may cause further problems like your situation.

Comment: Could be - the value is actually calculated via a division. I've not specifically declared it.

Comment: Have you declared your property (info.Amount) as float or double?