# Converting Float to Long gives negative value

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion, long-integer

Why does converting back gives a -ve expression ?

```
float f = long.MaxValue;

Console.WriteLine("long to float: {0}",f);
Console.WriteLine("long Max: {0}",long.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine("float to long casting: {0}",(long)f);
//Console.WriteLine("converting float to long: {0}",Convert.ToInt64(f));
//Above statement gives OverflowExection as expected.
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
long to float: 9.223372E+18
long Max: 9223372036854775807
float to long casting: -9223372036854775808
```

---

Again, `long.MinValue` gives the correct result.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352213/long-in-float-why .. and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935564/error-in-float-to-long-conversion ..

Comment: @txtechhelp: The questioner in first link didn't know how integral and floating points are represented in memory and the questioner in the second link wanted to have exact value from a floating point type. But context of my question is different. Its ok if float doesn't give exact value, but negative value ...?

Comment: You are not Converting to long. you are Casting to long. and well that's kind of different!

Comment: yup that was explicit casting, I tried converting too..same result. Added to the question.

Comment: float f = long.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt64(f));
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: @GaneshR. yes you are right !. I was using LinqPad 4 which gave the above result. I should remove the convert version.

Comment: i  give answer as comment! because im not sure. i dont have reference. i thinks its because float is floating-point and not accurate. it will become out of range of long (since it was already long.max) and casting just gives unexpected resault (i dont know why). but if you try  `Convert.ToInt64` you will get Overflow exception.

Comment: Yes that's the answer. I just checked the value of float result, its 1 more than long.MaxValue (you can see the output). Please write it as an answer and  I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M.kazem suggested in the comment, it was resulting in an overflow and as per C# specification compiler was silently ignoring it

```
Console.WriteLine("float to long casting: {0}",(long)f);
```

But if we convert above under checked then an overflow expression is thrown.

```
checked 
{
   Console.WriteLine("float to long casting: {0}",(long)f);
}
```

Comment: yes. if i find why casting gives negative value ill let you know.

Comment: For C# projects, by default check for arithmetic overflow is disabled.

Comment: for the negative value i think the problem is top bit that specifies the sign of `long`. the same thing when you convert uint to int. if uint is more than `int.max` it gives negative because top bit specifies sign. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1131851/4767498