# Can someone explain variation in values while converting explicitly from float to other data types?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

```
Float f = 123456789F
```

**Output of float**

```
Float = 1.234568E+08
```

**Output shown while converting to**

```
Int = 123456792

Long = 123456792 

D = 123456792

String = 1.234568E+08
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: Due to precision, the value of float may not be the value you set, so errors will occur during conversion. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8911646/8335151

Comment: So, that means we can relay completely on conversation??

Answer (score 0):

- Float is number with a decimal point from -3.402823e38 to 3.402823e38
- Int is an integer from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
- Long is like int, but it has more space to use (from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)
- String is stored like a text, not the actuall number.

Comment: Yes, but int can store 123456789, but while converting same number from float, its showing different digit in the end.