# c# float to int cast returns wrong value

Tags: c#, casting

I tried to cast a float value to an int, using this line of C# code:

```
int x = (int)(10.0f * 0.9f);
```

For some reasons, x now has the value 8, and I really don't see why. Can somebody help?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is weird. It's probably resulting in something like 8.999999999999 and since you're casting to an int, the fractional component gets chopped. You could try `int x = (int)Math.Round(10.0f * 0.9f);` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911440/c-sharp-float-expression-strange-behavior-when-casting-the-result-float-to-int

Comment: That worked, thanks!