# Single-precision arithmetic broken when running x86-compiled code on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c#, floating-point, 64-bit, clr, single-precision

When you read [MSDN on `System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx):

> `Single` complies with the IEC 60559:1989 (IEEE 754) standard for binary
>   floating-point arithmetic.

and the C# Language Specification:

> The `float` and `double` types are represented using the 32-bit single-precision
>   and 64-bit double-precision IEEE 754 formats [...]

and later:

> The product is computed according to the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic.

you easily get the impression that the `float` type and its multiplication comply with IEEE 754.

It is a part of IEEE 754 that **multiplcation is well-defined**. By that I mean that when you have two `float` instances, there exists one and only one `float` which is their "correct" product. It is not permissible that the product depends on some "state" or "set-up" of the system calculating it.

Now, consider the following simple program:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Environment");
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem);
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess);
    bool isDebug = false;
#if DEBUG
    isDebug = true;
#endif
    Console.WriteLine(isDebug);
    Console.WriteLine();

    float a, b, product, whole;

    Console.WriteLine("case .58");
    a = 0.58f;
    b = 100f;
    product = a * b;
    whole = 58f;
    Console.WriteLine(whole == product);
    Console.WriteLine((a * b) == product);
    Console.WriteLine((float)(a * b) == product);
    Console.WriteLine((int)(a * b));
  }
}
```

Appart from writing some info on the environment and compile configuration, the program just considers two `float`s (namely `a` and `b`) and their product. The last four write-lines are the interesting ones. Here's the output of running this on a 64-bit machine after compiling with **Debug x86** (left), **Release x86** (middle), and **x64** (right):

[image: Debug x86 (left), Release x86 (middle), and x64 (right)]

We conclude that the result of simple `float` operations depends on the build configuration.

The first line after `"case .58"` is a simple check of equality of two `float`s. We expect it to be independent of build mode, but it's not. The next two lines we expect to be identical because it does not change anything to cast a `float` to a `float`. But they are not. We also expect them to read `"True↩ True"` because we're comparing the product `a*b` to itself. The last line of the output we expect to be independent of build configuration, but it's not.

To figure out what the correct product is, we calculate manually. The binary representation of `0.58` (`a`) is:

```
0 . 1(001 0100 0111 1010 1110 0)(001 0100 0111 1010 1110 0)...
```

where the block in parentheses is the period which repeats forever. The single-precision representation of this number needs to be rounded to:

```
0 . 1(001 0100 0111 1010 1110 0)(001      (*)
```

where we have rounded (in this case round down) to the nearest representable `Single`. Now, the number "one hundred" (`b`) is:

```
110 0100 .       (**)
```

in binary. Computing the full product of the numbers `(*)` and `(**)` gives:

```
 11 1001 . 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 0100
```

which rounded (in this case rounding up) to single-precision gives

```
 11 1010 . 0000 0000 0000 0000 00
```

where we rounded up because the next bit was `1`, not `0` (round to nearest). So we conclude that the result is `58f` according to IEEE. This was not in any way given *a priori*, for example `0.59f * 100f` is less than `59f`, and `0.60f * 100f` is greater than `60f`, according to IEEE.

So it looks like the x64 version of the code got it right (right-most output window in the picture above).

Note: If any of the readers of this question have an old 32-bit CPU, it would be interesting to hear what the output of the above program is on their architecture.

And now for the question:

1. Is the above a bug?
2. If this is not a bug, where in the [C# Specifcation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) does it say that the runtime may choose to perform a `float` multiplication with extra precision and then "forget" to get rid of that precision again?
3. How can casting a `float` expression to the type `float` change anything?
4. Isn't it a problem that seemingly innocent operations like splitting an expression into two expressions by e.g. pulling out an `(a*b)` to a temprary local variable, changes behavior, when they ought to be mathematically (as per IEEE) equivalent? How can the programmer know in advance if the runtime chooses to hold the `float` with "artificial" extra (64-bit) precision or not?
5. Why are "optimizations" from compiling in Release mode allowed to change arithmetics?

(This was done in the 4.0 version of the .NET Framework.)

Comment: And this is why we should never check for floating point equality ;p

Comment: @leppie Well, checking for "less than" or "greater than" (even after adding or subtracting some `epsilon`) also produces unpredictable results, in an entirely similar way. So when ever your program uses a floating-point variable somewhere, you can never know if the program does the same, consistently, because floating-point operations in the CLR are unpredictable?

Comment: I was being slightly sarcastic. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't checked your arithmetic, but I've certainly seen similar results before. As well as debug mode making a difference, assigning to a local variable vs an instance variable can make a difference too. This is legitimate as per section 4.1.6 of the C# 4 specification:

> Floating point operations may be performed with higher precision than the result type of the operation. For example, some hardware architectures support an "extended" or "long double" floating point type with greater range and precision than the `double` type, and implicitly perform all floating point operations using this higher precision type. Only at excessive cost in performance can such hardware architectures be made to perform floating point operations with *less* precision. Rather than require an implementation to forfeit performance and precision, C# allows a higher precision type to be used for all floating point operations. Other than delivering more precise results, this rarely has any measurable effects. [...]

I can't say for sure whether that's what's going on here, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: That's exactly what's going on here.  Since it conforms to the language specification, it's not a bug, though it is somewhat unfortunate (one could try to argue that it's a bug in the language specification).

Comment: @StephenCanon I agree. The above quote (thanks, Jon, it was exactly what I asked for, item 2.) kind of says: "OK, we're not IEEE compliant after all; we use the precision of the hardware. We know it's not equivalent to IEEE, but we still do it."

Comment: Jon, do you happen to also know the answer to "How can casting a `float` expression to the type `float` change anything?" Most programmers (and development tools) would think that cast was a no-op and remove it. Also, one could think that the compiler disregarded it. But it looks like this is some "secret" feature. Or is this also part of the C# Language Specification?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Sorry, only just seen this. No idea about the casting bit. I think I could do with an example which *just* shows that to investigate further.

Comment: It would be very nice if you would investigate this some more. But I have myself found some references for it. In the accepted answer of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795550/), Eric Lippert seems to confirm that casting a `float` to type `float` will change something. And in an old version of a [text by you(!)](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/floatingpoint.html), it says in a parenthesis "_Casting `g` to float [...] has the same effect, even though it looks like a no-op_". The formulation is changed in later versions of your text, however.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thanks for pointing out the text from Eric - very helpful, as ever...

Comment: I found other threads here on SO on this, and the conclusion seems to be that the floating-point operations are not "well-defined" or "predictable/deterministic", meaning that if the same multiplication is done twice, it might not yield the same result (not even within the same instance of a running program). Instead the result depends on whether the runtime chooses to use extra precision or not, and we can never tell if it does. In my opinion, it's a shame to call that IEEE 754 compliant.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I wish languages or frameworks would define both precise-width floating-point types and minimum-width floating-point types, to allow code to specify when it's using e.g. a 32-bit float because it wants the precise semantics of that type, versus using that type to maximize speed and minimize memory footprint.  While "fast hope-for-the-best" semantics are sometimes useful, a good platform should not make it hard to get deterministic semantics when needed.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed. Java has -strictfp (or whatever the flag is called; I forget now) which may or may not give *exactly* what's desirable here. It's nice to have at least something :)