# Why storing a value in a variable changes the outcome of equality comparison?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Output of the following code:

```
var a = 0.1;
var count = 1;

while (a > 0)
{
    if (count == 323)
    {
        var isZeroA = (a * 0.1) == 0;
        var b = a * 0.1;
        var isZeroB = b == 0;

        Console.WriteLine("IsZeroA: {0}, IsZeroB: {1}", isZeroA, isZeroB);
    }

    a *= 0.1;
    ++count;
}
```

is

---

### IsZeroA: False, IsZeroB: True

Strangely, when I put a breakpoint after `if (count == 323)` while debugging and put expression `(a * 0.1) == 0` in Visual Studio Watch window, it reports that expression is `true`.

Does anyone know why expression `a * 0.1` is not zero, but when assigned to a variable `b`, then `b` is zero?

Comment: Use decimal instead of double if you expect accurate results

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would like to know why this is happening. If you have some expression which evaluates to one value and then assign that expression to a variable of the same type and then that variable evaluates to a different value. Why is this happening if both expression and variable are of the same type and use equal amount of storage space?

Comment: Computers count with 2 fingers, not 10 fingers like you do.  When you have 2 fingers then 0.1 cannot be expressed with a limited number of digits.  Just like you cannot express 1/3 with 10 fingers.  You'd have to write 0.3333... and you'll eventually run out of paper.  If you multiply that number by 3 then you don't get 1, you get 0.9999...  The amount of paper a computer uses is small, System.Double can store up to 15 accurate digits.

Comment: @HansPassant Same thing happens when you use a number that is perfectly comfortable in two-finger counting - e.g. 0.5, 0.25, or 0.125. It just happens at a later step ([demo](http://ideone.com/6iJIpt)).

Comment: I can't think of a reason for this other than a bug in optimizer. C# tries to save on computation, decides that in order for `a * 0.1` to be zero `a` must be zero. This is true in mathematics, but not true in `double`s. It appears that the code sets `IsZeroA` based on the value of `a`, not based on the value of `a` times constant.

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of "floating point math being broken" questions.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually, computers often count with 32 fingers, and differentiate between a "bent" and a "stretched" finger. You can count up to 1023 with 10 fingers (but be careful when showing someone the number "4" ...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does not happen with my particular hardware and CLR version. *Edit:* Oh yes, it happen to me too, if I use **"x86"** (or "Any CPU" with "Prefer 32-bit" enabled) and **"Debug"** mode.

The reason why things like that may sometimes happen, is that the system may hold the value in a 80-bit CPU registry where it has "extra" precision. But when put into a real 64-bit `Double`, it changes value.

If you change into:

```
var isZeroA = (double)(a * 0.1) == 0;
```

then formally you really change nothing (a cast from `double` to `double`!), but in reality that may force the run-time to convert from 80-bit to 64-bit. Does it change the output for you? *Edit:* This "no-op" cast changes something for me! For more on such cast-to-self tricks with floating-point types in C#, see other thread [*Casting a result to float in method returning float changes result*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795550/).

Note that `Double` arithmetic is ***not*** deterministic (i.e. the same calculation can give different results when repeated) because of these 64-bit/80-bit issues. See other thread [*Is floating-point math consistent in C#? Can it be?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683059/)

---

The following simpler program also shows the issue in cases where it is present (at least on my system):

```
double j = 9.88131291682493E-324;
Console.WriteLine(j * 0.1 == 0);             // "False"
double k = j * 0.1;
Console.WriteLine(k == 0);                   // "True"

Console.WriteLine((double)(j * 0.1) == 0);   // "True", double-to-double cast!
```

You can even start with `j = 1E-323` in that code. It leads to the same `Double`.

---

Reference: The often cited document [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg appears in the internet with [an added section *Differences Among IEEE 754 Implementations*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#3098) by an anonymous author (which is not Goldberg). This section, ***Differences Among IEEE 754 Implementations***, explains the issue you see in a technical manner.

Also see [x86 Extended Precision Format (Wikipedia page section)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) about this 80-bit format.

Comment: Could you please try running [this example](http://ideone.com/6iJIpt) on your system, and see if you get a printout at some point?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It depends on wheter I use x86 or x64, and whether I use Debug or Release.

Comment: Happens to me also in Release.

Comment: It probably depends on multiple factors: Debug vs. Release, whether optimizations are enabled (`/optimize+`), compiler version, target platform, ... The lesson is to never ever rely on floating-point equality comparisons without using an epsilon.