# Casting Results of Float Multiplication Produces Differing Results if the Float is First Saved to a Variable?

Tags: c#, casting, precision, floating-accuracy

The code here is straight forward but I don't understand the results:

```
float percent = 0.69f;
int firstInt = (int)(percent*100f);

float tempFloat = percent*100f;
int secondInt = (int)tempFloat;

Debug.Log(firstInt + " " + secondInt);
```

Why is `firstInt` 68 but `secondInt` is 69?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YMJExy - result is `69 69`..

Comment: Local machine, I get the `68 69` result.

Comment: It looks like `69` can't be accurately represented by a float and actually comes out to something like 68.999999... Changing your second line of code to `int firstInt = (int)Math.Ceiling(percent*100f);` gives you 69. No idea why assigning that 68.99999... to a float variable "corrects" the problem though.

Comment: On my local machine, I get `68 68` with optimizations enabled, and `68 69` without. Weird.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Same here. VS 2015. Targeting framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Here's an answer from Mr. Lippert: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8795656/1141432

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the compiler has figured out the value of the

```
percent*100f
```

expression using double math, and optimized away the computation. This is not allowed when intermediate results are saved in a float variable.

Since .69 does not have anexact representation in float or in double, the two representations "land" on different sides of an int: double is slightly above, while float is slightly below the actual value of .69.

Comment: This does seem to be a possible correct answer, I'm surpirsed that the compiler thinks a reasonable optimisation for a `float` calculation is to do it as a `double` though. When it's just blatantly changing the output and there are no hardware (runtime) considerations to be made since it's just plonking the value in the output. Do you know why it does this?

Comment: Ah no worries, the answer to my question is in the other answers from the comments, the C# compiler can pretty much use more precision whenever it likes if given the option, as you say, storing it as a `float` prevents it from doing that.