# Can precision of floating point numbers in Javascript be a source of non determinism?

Tags: javascript, math, non-deterministic

Can the same mathematical operation return different results in different architectures or browsers ?

Comment: Floats move in mysterious ways.

Comment: Post your code and find out ;)

Comment: I have no code... Was just wondering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the ECMAScript language specification 5.1 edition states that numbers are primitive values corresponding to IEEE 754 floats, which implies calculations *should be* consistent:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ecma-st/ECMA-262.pdf

> 4.3.19 Number value
>
> primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value
>
> NOTE
>       A Number value is a member of the Number type and is a direct representation of a number.

As [BlueRaja](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10338202/1151724) points out, there is a sort of caveat in section 15.8.2:

> The behaviour of the functions acos, asin, atan, atan2, cos, exp, log,
>   pow, sin, sqrt, and tan is not  precisely specified here...

Meaning, these are at least some cases where the outcome of *operations on numbers* is implementation dependent and may therefore be inconsistent.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The same machine can return different results for an operation like x + y even if x and y are the same. BlueRaja's answer is correct.

Comment: Okay I agree with @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft -- however, I can't delete this answer since it has been accepted, so I've edited.

Answer (score 16):

The other answers are incorrect.  According to the [ECMAScript 5.1 specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (section 15.8.2)

> NOTE The behaviour of the functions acos, asin, atan, atan2, cos, exp,
>   log, pow, sin, sqrt, and tan is not  precisely specified here except
>   to require specific results for certain argument values that represent
>   boundary cases of  interest.
>
> ...
>
> Although the choice of algorithms is
>   left to the implementation, it is recommended (but not specified by
>   this standard) that  implementations use the approximation algorithms
>   for IEEE 754 arithmetic contained in  fdlibm, the freely distributable
>   mathematical library from Sun Microsystems

---

However, even if the implementations *were* specified, the exact results of **all** floating-point operations would *still* be dependent on browser/architecture.  **That includes simple operations like multiplication and division!!**

The reason is that IEEE-754 allows systems to do 64-bit floating-point calculations at a [higher-precision than the result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#IEEE_754_extended_precision_formats), leading to different rounding results than systems which use the same precision as the result.  This is exactly what the [x86 (Intel) architecture does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format), which is why in C (and javascript) we can sometimes have [`cos(x) != cos(y)` even though `x == y`](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.18), even on the same machine!

This is a [big issue for networked peer-to-peer games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683059/are-floating-point-numbers-consistent-in-c-can-they-be), since this means, if the higher-precision calculations can't be disabled *(as is the case for C#)*, those games pretty much *can't use floating-point calculations at all.*  However, this is typically not an issue for Javascript games, since they are usually client-server.

Comment: Great post -- but: in general (because of imprecision) using == or != with floats is not a good idea.  However, it doesn't mean you can't use floats, it just means, don't use == or !=, use comparative <= >= ranges tailored to whatever degree of precision.

Comment: @goldilocks is right, infact (Math.tan(1) == Math.sin(1)/Math.cos(1)) yields false...

Comment: @João: Yes, but that is orthogonal to your question.  Everyone knows we might have `tan(1) != sin(1)/cos(1)`, due to floating-point inaccuracies.  The question was not whether they would be equal, but rather if `tan(x)` will always be exactly the same thing in all browsers/machines for some `x`.  The answer to that is still NO, but has nothing to do with floating-point inaccuracy - it's because `tan(x)` is not precisely defined in javascript, and because IEEE-754 allows extended-precision calculations.  If those two things weren't true, the answer would be yes, it's always the same.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question _about JavaScript_.  Addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division are precisely defined to have IEEE 754 semantics, and as far as I am aware there is no provision in the ECMAScript standard, nor any noteworthy JavaScript implementation, that allows extended precision evaluation of expressions like C does.  ([References and comparison to C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66164241).)  If there is such a provision, please cite it!

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that every browser vendor follows the *IEEE* standards + ECMA specs and there is no human error while implementing, no there can't be any difference.

Comment: Yeah, if they comply with the standards, they all behave in standard ways. Browsers that don't comply with IEEE/ECMA are probably not worth using anyway.

Comment: Ah, now that you have added "ECMA" I can delete my answer and upvote yours. =) Further information for readers: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf specifies how all ECMAscript numbers must behave, usually in terms of various IEEE specifications.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: You're incorrect aswell. At the end its the same problem that `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3`. But that seems to be a problem of a higher order which happens to any system that follows IEEE there. So technically, there should be NO difference in those results (even if they are wrong).

Comment: The result of a floating-point multiplication (and possibly addition) could be different on different systems that follow IEEE-754 *(see my answer for the reason why)*, so you are wrong on that point.  Moreover, the result of, say, `cos(1)` is not specified by the ECMA specs, so that can differ in implementation between different browsers as well.  So the answer to OP's question is a resounding **YES**.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents - @goldilocks notes and others allude to that you shouldn't use == or != on floating point numbers.  So what do you mean by "deterministic"?  That the behavior is always the same on different machines?  Obviously this depends on what you mean by "the same behavior."

Well, at one silly literal level of "the same," of course not, physical bits will be different on e.g. 32 bit versus 64 bit machines.  So that interpretation is out.

Ok, so will any program run with the same output on two different machines?  In general languages no, because a C program can do something with undefined memory, like read from an uninitialized bit.

Ok, so will any *valid* program do the same thing on different machines?  Well, I would say a program that uses == and != on floating point numbers is as invalid as a program that reads uninitialized memory.  I personally don't know if the Javascript standard hammers out the behavior of == and != on floats to the point that it's well-defined if not kooky, so if that is your precise question you'll have to see the other answers.  Can you write javascript code that has undefined output with respect to the standard?  Never read the standard (other answers cover this somewhat), but for my interest this is moot because the programs that would produce what you call undeterministic behavior are invalid to begin with.

Comment: Even if we never use equality comparison, there would still be undeterministic behavior. Since in game, the calculation can happen 60 times or more a second, any error will be quickly accumulated.