# Is Math.floor(x/y) deterministic?

Tags: javascript, integer-division, deterministic

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10338202/1778374) post, floating point numbers in JavaScript are not deterministic.

I wonder, is the following code deterministic?

```
z = Math.floor(x/y)
```

If not, how can I do deterministic integer division in JavaScript?

Edit: I would like to know if I can rely on the resulting value being the same across different JavaScript implementations (given they follow the standards).

Comment: "implementation dependent" and "nondeterministic" are not exactly the same concept. The latter tends to refer to functions which depend on random numbers, which isn't really the issue here.

Comment: To clarify: In my question I am asking for an implementation independent method of dividing whole numbers in javascript

Comment: Your question is perfectly clear, just not what I expected given its title.

Answer (score 1):

It should be deterministic.

According to [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.floor)

> 20.2.2.16 Math.floor ( x )
>
> Returns the greatest (closest to +∞) Number value that is not greater than x and is equal to a mathematical integer. If x is already an integer, the result is x.
>
> - If x is NaN, the result is NaN.
> - If x is +0, the result is +0.
> - If x is −0, the result is −0.
> - If x is +∞, the result is +∞.
> - If x is −∞, the result is −∞.
> - If x is greater than 0 but less than 1, the result is +0.
>
> **NOTE** The value of Math.floor(x) is the same as the value of -Math.ceil(-x).

The non-determinism of some Math functions has to do with possible rounding issues when the underlying engine uses higher-precision numbers.  That shouldn't be a factor here.

**Update** :

Division is [also deterministic](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.2).  Here the JS specification depends on the IEEE 754 specification.  But that specification is deterministic.  (Sorry no link, as the actual specification is paywalled.)

The non-determinisim is in the less common JS functions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, x / y may result in a different value depending on the architecture. Could these rounding errors "leak" through the Math.floor function?

Comment: Updated.  I've never actually read the IEEE 754 specification, but I've been told that its division algorithm is deterministic as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  Math.floor always returns a lowest **integer** value.

Whereas this is not deterministic:
`z = 3/1.5; //z !== 2`

This, by the function's design, is:
`z = Math.floor(3/1.5); //z === 2`

See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) for more details.