# casting a float number into int number will result to invalid int

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, int, type-conversion

I write below code:

```
 int vat = (int)(invoice.total * 0.08f);
```

assume invoice.total = 36000. then `vat` must be 2880 but is 2879!
I changed my code to

```
float v = invoice.total * 0.08f;
int vat = (int)v;
```

Now `vat` has correct value (2880).

I wonder if `()` has more priority or not! and also float is exact 2880.0 not a little less, so no rounding must happen!

Comment: It is non-reproducible. http://ideone.com/NnuB2e

Comment: I can reproduce too... (it does not seem to matter whether you use 36000 or 36000f...)

Comment: Mmm, it IS reproducible, surprisingly: http://ideone.com/USiCEX

Comment: Is the `total` property/field (in the `invoice`) of type `float`, or of type `int` (or similar)?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>A `float` holds some "hidden" precision that is not shown. Try watching `invoice.total.ToString("R")`, and you will probably see that it is not exactly `36000`.</strike>

Alternatively, this can be a result of your runtime choosing a "broader" storage location, like a 64-bit or 80-bit CPU register or similar, for the intermediate result `invoice.total * 0.08f`.

**EDIT:** You can throw away the effects arising from the runtime choosing a too wide storage location, by changing

```
(int)(invoice.total * 0.08f)
```

into

```
(int)(float)(invoice.total * 0.08f)
```

The extra cast, from `float` to `float` (sic!), looks like a no-op, but it does force the runtime to round and throw away that unwanted precision. This is poorly documented. [Will provide reference.] A related thread you might want to read: [Are floating-point numbers consistent in C#? Can they be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683059/)

---

Your example is actually archetypical, so I have decided to go a bit more into detail. This stuff is well described in the section [Differences Among IEEE 754 Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#3098) which is written as an addendum (by an anonymous author) to David Goldberg's *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*. So suppose we have this code:

```
static int SO_24548957_I()
{
  float t = 36000f; // exactly representable
  float r = 0.08f;  // this is not representable, rounded

  float temporary = t * r;
  int v = (int)temporary;

  return v; // always(?) 2880
}
```

Everything seems fine, but we decide to refactor the temporary variable away, so we write:

```
static int SO_24548957_II()
{
  float t = 36000f; // exactly representable
  float r = 0.08f;  // this is not representable, rounded

  int v = (int)(t * r);

  return v; // could be 2880 or 2879 depending on strange things
}
```

and Bang! the behavior of our program changes. You can see the change on most systems (at least on mine!) if you compile for platform `x86` (or `Any CPU` with `Prefer 32-bit` selected). Optimizations or not (Release or Debug mode) could be relevant in theory, and the hardware architecture is certainly important too.

It is a complete surprise to many that both 2880 and 2879 can be correct answers on IEEE-754-compliant systems, but read the link I gave.

To elaborate over what is meant by "not representable", let us see what the C# compiler must do when it encounters the symbol `0.08f`. Beacuse of the way `float` (32-bit binary floating point) works, we will have to choose between:

```
10737418 / 2**27  ==  0.079 999 998 2...
```

and

```
10737419 / 2**27  ==  0.080 000 005 6...
```

where `**` means exponentiation (i.e. "to the power of"). Since the first one is nearer to the desired mathematical value, we **must** choose that one. So the actual value is a bit smaller than the desired one. Now when we do the multiplication *and want to store in a `Single` again* we must also, as a part of the multiplication algorithm, round again to yield the product representation which is closest to the exact "mathematical" product of the (actual) factors `36000` and `0.0799999982...`. In this case you are *lucky* that the nearest `Single` is actually `2880` exactly, so the multiplication process in our case involves a round-up to this value.

Therefore the first code example above gives `2880`.

However, in the second code example above, the multiplication might be done (at the choice of the run-time, we cannot really help that) in some CPU hardware that handles many bits (64 or 80, typically). In that case, the product of any two 32-bit floats, like ours, can be calculated without need for rounding the end result, because 64 bits or 80 bits are more than enough to hold the full product of two 32-bit floats. So clearly this product is smaller than `2880` since
`0.0799999982...` is less than `0.08`.

Therefore the second method example above *could* return `2879`.

For comparison, this code:

```
static int SO_24548957_III()
{
  float t = 36000f; // exactly representable
  float r = 0.08f;  // this is not representable, rounded

  double temporary = t * (double)r;
  int v = (int)temporary;

  return v; // always(?) 2879
}
```

always give the `2879` because we explicitly tell the compile to convert the `Single` to `Double` which means adding a bunch of binary zeroes, so we get to the `2879` case with certainty.

*Lessons learned:* (1) With binary floating points, fatoring out a sub-expression to a temp variable might change the result. (2) With binary floating points, C# compiler settings like `x86` vs. `x64` might change the result.

---

Of course, as everybody says everywhere, do not use `float` or `double` for monetary applications; use `decimal` there.

Comment: 36000 is exactly representable

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's for sure, but a number like `36000.0039f` or `35999.9961f` has a representation that is distinct from `36000f`, yet both look the same when printed in usual formatting. So just because a number _looks_ like 36,000 (which is exactly representable) it could be a different number. However, because the output changes if he uses a temp varaible, I have stroke out that part of my answer now.

Comment: The thing is that if `invoice.total` is an `int` with value 36000 then the behaviour is as described in the question. But what you say could certainly be true as well. It just isn't needed to explain the output.

Answer (score 1):

0.08f is not exactly representable. The [closest single precision value](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.08) is

```
0.07999999821186065673828125
```

So you actually calculate

```
36000 * 0.07999999821186065673828125
```

which is just a little less than `2880`. You then truncate the value, and hence receive the value `2879`.

This might be the first time you have encountered an issue like this, but I bet you were not expecting that the actual value of `0.08f` would be `0.07999999821186065673828125`.

Consider this variant:

```
float f = 36000 * 0.08f;
Console.WriteLine((int)f);
double d1 = 36000 * 0.08f;
Console.WriteLine((int)d1);
double d2 = 36000 * 0.08d;
Console.WriteLine((int)d2);
```

which outputs

```
2880
2879
2880
```

Why do your two variants behave differently? Because the compiler is choosing to store an intermediate value for `invoice.total * 0.08f` to a precision other than single.

---

Clearly you are playing with fire here. This behaviour is all down to fundamental property of floating point arithmetic. Your choice of **binary** floating point inevitable leads to issues like this. One way to get around this is to round the values to the nearest integer.

```
float f = 36000 * 0.08f;
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(f));
double d1 = 36000 * 0.08f;
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(d1));
double d2 = 36000 * 0.08d;
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(d2));
```

which results in

```
2880
2879
2880
```

You might also consider using `Decimal` for calculations like this. That way you operate on decimal rather than binary representations and so will be able to represent all these values exactly.

```
int vat = (int)(36000 * 0.08m);
Console.WriteLine(vat);
```

which outputs

```
2880
```

Exactly how to solve the problem depends very much on the details of the calculation and your business logic. But the fundamental issue is that binary floating point cannot represent your calculations exactly.

Comment: and: (int) will truncate the floating point number, not round it. However, that's not the problem. Both statements should produce the same value, whether it's 2880 or not

Comment: Technically, from a C# perspective, in the first version, the expression `invoice.total * 0.08f` is ***not*** a `double` like you claim. It is a product of two floats/singles, hence a float itself. *Addition:* The difference comes because the runtime chooses to "hold" the `float` (32-bit) intermediate value in a storage location with "too much precision". The result is not required to be `2879`.

Comment: @David Hefferman if invoice.total were decimal, invoice.total * 0.08f wouldn't compile in C# without explicit cast. If invoice.total were double, it would compile and technically be double, but some precision was already lost on writing 0.08f as float and not double. But in this case invoice.total can't be double as it is assigned to float v without explicit cast, which couldn't be done if double.

Comment: OK all, you got me there. It must be as Jeppe says.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to Jeppe's and David's answer regarding the compiler choosing a different precision of an intermediate value.

Your first expression, written in a function like:

```
static int Calc1(int value)
{
    float v = value * 0.08f;
    return (int) v;
}
```

will result in the following IL code:

```
.method private hidebysig static int32  Calc1(int32 'value') cil managed
{
    // Code size       12 (0xc)
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init ([0] float32 v)
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  conv.r4
    IL_0002:  ldc.r4     7.9999998e-002
    IL_0007:  mul
    IL_0008:  stloc.0
    IL_0009:  ldloc.0
    IL_000a:  conv.i4
    IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method Program::Calc1
```

Note, that the instructions `stloc.0` and `ldloc.0` convert the multiplication result to a *float* before the final conversation to an *int* (`conv.i4`) takes place.

Now let's look at your second expression:

```
static int Calc2(int value)
{
    return (int)(value * 0.08f);
}
```

and the according IL code:

```
.method private hidebysig static int32  Calc2(int32 'value') cil managed
{
    // Code size       10 (0xa)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  conv.r4
    IL_0002:  ldc.r4     7.9999998e-002
    IL_0007:  mul
    IL_0008:  conv.i4
    IL_0009:  ret
} // end of method Program::Calc2
```

Note that the result of the multiplication is directly converted to an *int*.

The multiplication result has the precision as provided by the floating point CPU instructions chosen by the JIT compiler, which most likely will exceed the precision of the *float* format. Thus, the first code incurs an additional loss of precision due to the *float* conversion of the multiplication result. The second code does not suffer from this additional precision loss, as it avoids the intermediate *float* conversion.

(Actually, for the first code example the JIT compiler might be smart enough to instruct the CPU to do floating point arithmetic with single precision only, thus already doing the multiplication with the low single precision.)

You might want to argue that the `stloc.0` `ldloc.0` combo in the IL cod of the first example is pointless and should be optimized away if the compiler would just be smart enough. Alas, this is not the case. Look again at the C# code of the first example. There, the source code explicitly demands that the multiplication result must be converted into a *float* value (via the variable *v*). The `stloc.0` `ldloc.0` combo is merely the way the compiler did choose to adhere to this demanded *float* conversion.