# Unity 2017 vs Unity 5.x "float" differs

Tags: unity-game-engine, floating-point

```
Debug.Log((int)(4.2f * 10.0f));
```

Result : 41 (in Unity 2017.2.1p4)

Result : 42 (in Unity 5.4.3p4)

why it differs??

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: hmm... I think result of 4.2f * 10.0f = 41.9999998f

Comment: then it converts to int as 41. but why it is 42 in Unity 5.4.3p4?

Comment: @연어회무침: Probably a different rounding mode, or it converts to double (exactly: 4.2 --> 
 4.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125)

Comment: Possibly a change in the C# version. I always assume that the fractional part is just dropped, but maybe the newer version is rounding. Given that this is essentially a float-precision error, try running in a loop a few thousand times and counting how many times it spits back 41 or 42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact result of product of (single precision) float `4.2f` and `10.f` is

```
41.9999980926513671875
```

The nearest float to this exact result is `42.0f`

But this exact result fits in a double precision, so if ever the expression is evaluated in single precision it will print 42, but if it is evaluated in double precision, then it will print 41.

IOW, the expression can be decomposed into:

```
x = 4.2f;
x = x * 10.0f;
Debug.Log((int)(x));
```

If the compiler decided to preserve a single precision x, it will print 42, but if it decided to evaluate x in double precision, it will print 41.

Comment: how did you know that the exact result is 41.9999980926513671875 ??

Comment: Emulate the decimal (4.2f) to binary conversion (by repeated division and emulating the rounding mode - to nearest float, tie to even), then emulate binary to decimal conversion. By hand it's overkill, but there are several language that can do that - if conforming strictly enough to IEEE 754 standards (I use Squeak Smalltalk `(ArbitraryPrecisionFloat readFrom: '4.2' numBits: 24) asTrueFraction printShowingMaxDecimalPlaces: 100`.  In C, it could be as simple as `printf("%.20f\n',4.2f)` if printf does correctly its job of rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point numbers use an approximate representation and floatng math is not deterministic. The same calculation can give different results, particularly on different computers, architectures, or compiler and optimization settings.

Thus, it's likely that there is a difference in compiler and optimization settings between Unity 5.4.3p4 and Unity 2017.2.1p4.

In your example, `4.2f * 10.0f` can result in different values like `41.9999998f` or `42.0000002f`, which is casted to integer as 41 or 42 respectively.

For more information, see these posts:

- [Is floating-point math consistent in C#? Can it be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6683059/5170571)
- [Is floating point math deterministic?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2009/03/25/is-floating-point-math-deterministic/)